# Load more button value according "WHERE" Clouse condition

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am using load more button to load content from the database of specific id on the same web page. Here is the code:

```
<div class="postList col-lg-12">
     <legend><h1 style="color:#298208;">Savings Bucks Details</h1> </legend>
<?php
    $busi_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_SESSION['busi_id']);

    if (isset($busi_id)) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM savingsbucks_business WHERE busi_id='$busi_id' ORDER BY sbb_id DESC LIMIT 2";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
        $numrows_savingsbucks = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($numrows_savingsbucks == '0') {
        echo "<p style='text-align:center; color:#ff4400; margin-top:40px;'>No Data available!</p>";
    } else {
 ?>

<div class="table-responsive">
    <table border="1" class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
        <th class="consumer_point_text">Shop ID</th>
        <th class="consumer_point_text">SenderID</th>
        <th class="consumer_point_text">Busi ID</th>
        <th class="consumer_point_text">Customer Type</th>
        <th class="consumer_point_text">Customer Name</th>
        <th class="consumer_point_text">Customer Email</th>
        <th class="consumer_point_text">Customer Phone</th>
        <th class="consumer_point_text">Two</th>
        <th class="consumer_point_text">Five</th>
        <th class="consumer_point_text">Ten</th>
        <th class="consumer_point_text">Twenty</th>
        <th class="consumer_point_text">Fifty</th>
        <th class="consumer_point_text">Hundred</th>
        <th class="consumer_point_text">Five Hundred</th>
        <th class="consumer_point_text">Total Savings Bucks</th>

    </thead>
<?php if($numrows_savingsbucks > 0){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $sbb_id = $row['sbb_id'];
        $sender_id = $row['sender_id'];
        $busi_id = $row['busi_id'];
        $type = $row['type'];
        $consu_name = $row['consu_name'];
        $consu_email = $row['consu_email'];
        $consu_phone = $row['consu_phone'];
        $two = $row['two'];
        $five = $row['five'];
        $ten = $row['ten'];
        $twenty = $row['twenty'];
        $fifty = $row['fifty'];
        $hundred = $row['hundred'];
        $five_hundred = $row['five_hundred'];
        $total_two += $two;
        $total_five += $five;
        $total_ten += $ten;
        $total_twenty += $twenty;
        $total_fifty += $fifty;
        $total_hundred += $hundred;
        $total_five_hundred += $five_hundred;
        $total_bucks = $two+$five+$ten+$twenty+$fifty+$hundred+$five_hundred;
        $grand_total += $total_bucks;
?>

    <tr>
        <td class="consumer_point_text"><?=$sbb_id?></td>
        <td class="consumer_point_text"><?=$sender_id?></td>
        <td class="consumer_point_text"><?=$busi_id?></td>
        <td class="consumer_point_text" style="text-transform:capitalize;"><?=$type?></td>
        <td class="consumer_point_text"><?=$consu_name?></td>
        <td class="consumer_point_text"><?=$consu_email?></td>
        <td class="consumer_point_text"><?=$consu_phone?></td>
        <td class="consumer_point_text"><?=$two?></td>
        <td class="consumer_point_text"><?=$five?></td>
        <td class="consumer_point_text"><?=$ten?></td>
        <td class="consumer_point_text"><?=$twenty?></td>
        <td class="consumer_point_text"><?=$fifty?></td>
        <td class="consumer_point_text"><?=$hundred?></td>
        <td class="consumer_point_text"><?=$five_hundred?></td>
        <td class="consumer_point_text"><?=$total_bucks?></td>
    </tr>

<?php } ?>      
</table>

<div class="show_more_main" sbb_id="show_more_main<?php echo $sbb_id; ?>">
    <span sbb_id="<?php echo $sbb_id; ?>" class="show_more" title="Load more posts">Load more</span>
    <span class="loding" style="display: none;"><span class="loding_txt">Loading...</span></span>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script
<script src="http://demos.codexworld.com/includes/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.show_more',function(){
    var ID = $(this).attr('sbb_id');
    $('.show_more').hide();
    $('.loding').show();
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'ajax_more_business_shop.php',
        data:'sbb_id='+ID,
        success:function(html){
            $('#show_more_main'+ID).remove();
            $('.postList').append(html);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>

<?php }  ?> 
</div> <!-- ./col-lg-12 -->
<?php } }?>
```

On this page its displaying 2 results  which  have common busi_id (WHERE busi_id=$busi_id), when I click on load more button, its displaying others  content too which don't have same "busi_id" as on this page showing first 2 results. 
Here is ajax page:

ajax_more_business_shop.php :

```
<?php
    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED); 

if(!empty($_POST["sbb_id"]))  {
    require_once ('admin/includes/config.php');
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num_rows FROM savingsbucks_business WHERE sbb_id < ".$_POST['sbb_id']." ORDER BY sbb_id DESC";

$result = mysqli_query ($conn, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$totalRowCount = $row['num_rows'];
$busi_id = $row['busi_id'];
$showLimit = 2;

$query = "SELECT * FROM savingsbucks_business WHERE sbb_id < ".$_POST['sbb_id']." ORDER BY sbb_id DESC LIMIT $showLimit";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result); 

?>

<table border="1" class="table table-bordered"> 
    <?php  
        if ($rowcount > '0') {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
    $sbb_id = $row['sbb_id'];
    $sender_id = $row['sender_id'];
    $busi_id = $row['busi_id'];
    $type = $row['type'];
    $consu_name = $row['consu_name'];
    $consu_email = $row['consu_email'];
    $consu_phone = $row['consu_phone'];
    $two = $row['two'];
    $five = $row['five'];
    $ten = $row['ten'];
    $twenty = $row['twenty'];
    $fifty = $row['fifty'];
    $hundred = $row['hundred'];
    $five_hundred = $row['five_hundred'];
    $total_two += $two;
    $total_five += $five;
    $total_ten += $ten;
    $total_twenty += $twenty;
    $total_fifty += $fifty;
    $total_hundred += $hundred;
    $total_five_hundred += $five_hundred;
    $total_bucks = $two+$five+$ten+$twenty+$fifty+$hundred+$five_hundred;
    $grand_total += $total_bucks;
?>

    <tr>
    <td class="consumer_point_text"><?=$sbb_id?></td>
    <td class="consumer_point_text"><?=$sender_id?></td>
    <td class="consumer_point_text"><?=$busi_id?></td>
    <td class="consumer_point_text"><?=$type?></td>
    <td class="consumer_point_text"><?=$consu_name?></td>
    <td class="consumer_point_text"><?=$consu_email?></td>
    <td class="consumer_point_text"><?=$consu_phone?></td>
    <td class="consumer_point_text"><?=$two?></td>
    <td class="consumer_point_text"><?=$five?></td>
    <td class="consumer_point_text"><?=$ten?></td>
    <td class="consumer_point_text"><?=$twenty?></td>
    <td class="consumer_point_text"><?=$fifty?></td>
    <td class="consumer_point_text"><?=$hundred?></td>
    <td class="consumer_point_text"><?=$five_hundred?></td>
    <td class="consumer_point_text"><?=$total_bucks?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } 
    ?>
</table>

<?php if($totalRowCount > $showLimit){ ?>

 <div class="show_more_main" sbb_id="show_more_main<?php echo $sbb_id; ?>">
        <span sbb_id="<?php echo $sbb_id; ?>" class="show_more" title="Load more posts">Show more</span>
        <span class="loding" style="display: none;"><span class="loding_txt">Loading...</span></span>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
    <?php
    }
 }
?>
```

I want, when i click "load more button", It must show/load 2 more row of content where busi_id will be common, I mean if busi_id=69, it should show/load only 2 more content/result from database  which have busi_id 69, not other data with different busi_id.

I tried to explain,

Thank you.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Comment: @Dharman, May you  help, for what i  came here .. please ?

Comment: Any one will help or suggest  me?

Answer (score 0):

I have just passed the "busi_id" to Ajax page... with load more button..

```
<div class="show_more_main" ds_id="show_more_main<?php echo $ds_id; ?>">
    <span ds_id="<?php echo $ds_id; ?>" busi_id="<?php echo $busi_id; ?>" class="show_more" title="Load more posts">Load more</span>
    <span class="" style="display: none;"><span class="loding_txt">Loading...</span></span>
</div>
```

And..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.show_more',function(){
    var ID = $(this).attr('ds_id');
    var Busi_id = $(this).attr('busi_id');

    $('.show_more').hide();
    $('.loding').show();
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'ajax_more_consumer_shop.php',

        data: {
            'ds_id': ID,
            'busi_id': Busi_id
            },


        success:function(html){
            $('#show_more_main'+ID).remove();
            $('.postList').append(html);
        }
    });
});
```

});

on ajax_more_business_shop.php....

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num_rows FROM savingsbucks_business WHERE ds_id < ".$_POST['ds_id']." AND busi_id=".$_POST["busi_id"]." ORDER BY ds_id DESC";
$result = mysqli_query ($conn, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$totalRowCount = $row['num_rows'];
$showLimit = 2;

$query = "SELECT * FROM savingsbucks_business WHERE ds_id < ".$_POST['ds_id']." AND busi_id=".$_POST["busi_id"]." ORDER BY ds_id DESC LIMIT $showLimit";
$result = mysqli_query ($conn, $query);
$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

Modified  the query.. and  get the desired  output.

Thanks!